# Move QtWidgets.QtWidget using mouse

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I want to move a QtWidgets.QtWidget using the mouse (**not** a **QPushButton**, **QLabel** etc.). I've searched everywhere on the web, but couldn't find an answer for this. **mousePressEvent** seemed to be the way, but it doesn't work.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_hGUI(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)

    def setupUi(self, hGUI):
        hGUI.setObjectName("hGUI")
        hGUI.resize(161, 172)
        hGUI.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 200))
        hGUI.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 200))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    hGUI = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_hGUI()
    ui.setupUi(hGUI)

    hGUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm using Python 3.5, I'm creating the GUI using Qt Designer, then translate it to python code.

Edit: I'm trying to move a borderless windows by click on it.

Comment: You're actually creating two widgets, `hGUI` and `ui`, and then modifying the attributes of `hGUI` from the `ui.setupUI()` method. Why have two widgets? Which one are you actually trying to move? Also, top-level widgets (`hGUI`, in your case) can be moved with the mouse without any extra work on your part. I can run this code and move the window just fine, so it's really not clear from your question what problem you're having.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I've tried to simplify my code for you guys to understand and I forgot to tell you that I'm trying to move a borderless window. I'm trying to move hGUI by click on its surface.

Comment: Ok, simplification is usually good. In that case, I still don't understand what problem you're having. If I run this code, a basic window (`hGUI`) appears, which I can drag around just fine with my cursor. Is that not the case for you? If so, there must be some code you've left out that disables moving the window or in some other way keeps some mouse events from being delivered to your window.

Comment: Here's the whole code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c4208d76bf8720cca4972f4d494a89a0
As you can see, there's no way to move the Widget, because it's borderless, I want to make it movable by clicking and holding on it.

Comment: OK, so you want a borderless widget that can be moved? As you guessed, the way to do this is to override the widget's `mousePressEvent()` handler function. This takes a `QMouseEvent`, which has the position of the event stored in it. You can then move the main widget to this position, by calling `QWidget.move()`. You said "it doesn't work"...what did you try?

Comment: I don't know how to add that to my code (so it would work), I've tried to copy-paste (with small edits to fit my code) what I've found on web, but it doesn't work.
For example, this:
`def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    self.offset = event.pos()

def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    x=event.globalX()
    y=event.globalY()
    x_w = self.offset.x()
    y_w = self.offset.y()
    self.move(x-x_w, y-y_w)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a really simple question sir,

Let's say you just have to have an variable that holds the position of your widget and interact with it according to your needs.

1. This position variable let's call it "oldPos".
2. Now inside your mouse press you update this position.
3. By the last but not least, you relate your "oldPos" and your mouseMove actual position and move your widget.
4. Wallahhhh, here we have a beautiful and simple movable widget by mouse events.

**Here is the simplest example.**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget

class MyMovableWidget(QWidget):
    """WToolBar is a personalized toolbar."""

    homeAction = None

    oldPos = QPoint()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

     def mousePressEvent(self, evt):
        """Select the toolbar."""
        self.oldPos = evt.globalPos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, evt):
        """Move the toolbar with mouse iteration."""

        delta = QPoint(evt.globalPos() - self.oldPos)
        self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
        self.oldPos = evt.globalPos()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    coolWidget = MyMovableWidget()
    coolWidget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***So simple isn't it? :D***

Comment: Thank you, it certainly makes things more clear for me. The thing that I had two widges was what confused me.

Comment: You are welcome man, although if you do the same if several widgets inside a QMainWindow, or even inside anoter QWidget, everything would be the same, you would just have to see if you wanted to move it globally or related to some of the other objects. It would change only the logic inside the mouse events, but same reasoning  :D

Answer (score -1):

I managed to make it work, thanks to @bnaecker for telling me that the code actually creates two widgets, I've replaced some stuff in my code. Basically, just edit the code generated when you translate the .ui to .py so it would only create one widget.
The most changes happened here:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.excepthook = excepthook
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    hGUI = QtWidgets.QWidget(flags=QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    ui = Ui_hGUI()
    ui.setupUi(hGUI)
    hGUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Edited to this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.excepthook = excepthook
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    hGUI = Ui_hGUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Add self.show() at the end of retranslateUi(self), replace every "hGUI" in the code with "self" or delete it if it's an argument (**except for controls like buttons and labels**).
Here are both codes, non-working one vs. working one: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0707b4fef11ae4b31cf56dc78dd3af80
Note: In the new code, the app is called "VirtualMemories".